# какое отличие фасада Redis от фасада Cache Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Получается фасад Cache может сохранять кэш в файле, Redis, БД  и т.д
А что сохранять через фасад Redis команды про него тут https://redis.io/commands?

Как правильно где что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фасад `Cache` предоставляет единое API для работы с кешированием (файл, Redis, Memcached) и т.д. То есть позволяет не зависеть от технологии, а просто писать универсально кеширование, а в случае чего через конфиг менять эту технологию на что угодно. Поэтому если у Вас Redis рассчитан только на кеширование — используйте этот фасад особо не задумываясь, функцинальности в нем хватает.

В то время как фасад `Redis` - это полнофункциональный инструмент для работы с БД Redis и ничем больше. Если нужны какие-то специфические функции от Redis и в целом работаете с БД как основной — используйте этот фасад.

Comment: так а сам Redis разве не для кеша только сделан? цельже просто сохранить и быстро вытянуть чтобы БД не нагружать Или в каких целях нужен редис если не для кеша?

Comment: @junior Для оперативного использования данных. Можно использовать для сессий, логгирования, тот же чат организовывать. Лучше погуглите за это всё, информации достаточно.